# ssrs preset color of each tab for exported excel

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have set "page break"  & "page name" for all tablix in a report created in ssrs, so I can get each tablix on a separate sheet when exported into Excel.

However I also want to set a specific color for each tab, so when it is exported into Excel, I get colored tabs. Is this possible?

Comment: Impossible. The color of tab is the property inside of Excel. It is not opened for SSRS to preset.